# express command is not working in ubuntu 14.04 LTS terminal

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, express, ubuntu-14.04

[image: Express command not working]

First thing I want to clear here that may be this question is duplicate.But I read all the question related on this topic in stack overflow but not got the solution.[image]

Please Help me. I just install ***Nodejs version*** in my Laptop on Ubuntu OS.For ensure that nodejs is install on my laptop, Using **node -v** I found the version of Node js which is **0.12.2**

and same for **npm** I follow same steps and it works for me.But when i install ' **express 4 version**'. I use which node command and it is working and show the path is /usr/bin/node and same for npm is **/usr/bin/npm.**
but when i check for express it is not working for me. I have number of time install express-generator using '**sudo npm install -g express-generator**' and it install the files but when I use express my_app command it print The program '**express'** is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install node-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:
`npm install -g express`

In most cases you do not need sudo.

Comment: I also use npm install  - g express  but not working

Comment: The command as you typed it is wrong, you can't have that space. If you ran the right command, you can also try restarting your terminal. But in most cases your npm binaries folder should be there already.

Comment: You probably don't have your global npm folder in your system path, try running it with the absolute path `/home/manjeet/npm-global/bin/express`

Comment: Yha that is right but can I access express on desktop folder

Comment: i dont know what you're asking. `cd ~/Desktop/new; /home/manjeet/npm-global/bin/express`

Comment: Thank you Plato for your important time I will try and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75185/discussion-between-manjeet-thakur-and-plato).